# PHP mysql show product in Happy hour at special time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project, a digital menu for a Bar.

Some products have a start time like "12:00:00" and an end time like "20:00:00"

If is 15:00:00 it is not a problem to check "start <= 15 AND end >= 15 "....

If I have a product with a start time like "20:00:00" and an end time like "03:00:00", I'm not sure how to display it.

How can I show products with end times like this?

Comment: you can use full datetime like '2018-04-28 20:00:00', and then use DateTime class to get the difference and check if it's time for a special juice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add an if condition to your query.

If endtime is smaller than start time:

```
If true, check if:
    NOW() is greater than your start time 
        and 
    at the same time smaller than your end time. 

If false: proceed the other way around - "start <= 15 AND end >= 15 " - BAU.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like this:

```
SELECT Columns
  FROM Menu
 WHERE Curtime() BETWEEN Start AND End
    OR (Start > End AND Curtime() NOT BETWEEN End AND Start );
```